# Вывод комментариев методом wall.getComments

Tags: javascript, vkontakte-api

У меня  есть вот такая [ссылка](https://api.vk.com/method/wall.getComments?owner_id=-30458160&post_id=24905&v=5.58)

Мне нужно брать из этого источника имена, текст и выводить на странице

Не имею понятия как выдрать из стороннего источника текст. Буду благодарен

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используем `ajax` с типом `jsonp`.

При получении данных, обрабатываем полученный `json` объект так, как нам захочется. В данном случае просто выводим текст в `div` с помощью `callback` функции.

```js
var url = 'https://api.vk.com/method/wall.getComments?owner_id=-30458160&post_id=24905&v=5.58';
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function( response ) {
      if (response && response.response.count > 0) {
        //console.log( response ); 
        response.response.items.forEach(function(item, i, arr) {
          $('#response-text').append(item.text + '<br/><br/>');          
        });
      }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="response-text"></div>
```

---

```js
 var url = 'https://api.vk.com/method/wall.getComments?owner_id=-30458160&post_id=24905&v=5.58';
 $.ajax({
   url: url,
   dataType: "jsonp",
   success: callback
 });

 function callback(response) {
   if (response && response.response.count > 0) {
     //console.log( response ); 
     response.response.items.forEach(function(item, i, arr) {
       $('#response-text').append(item.text + '<br/><br/>');
     });
   }
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="response-text"></div>
```

---

И желательно при запросе всё же отделить `url` и данные, которые в него передаются. Т.е. данные будут в блоке `data` аякс запроса. Что-то типа:

```
...
url: 'https://api.vk.com/method/wall.getComments',
data: {
  'owner_id': '-30458160',
  'post_id': '24905',
  'v': '5.58'
},
...
```

Comment: Благодарю!
Заметил, что приходиться обновляться, чтобы обновить данные. Возможно ли как-нибудь это пофиксить?

Comment: @endoneslife есессно. Надо привязывать вашу логику - когда эти данные нужны........ Если по клику на кнопку - то привязывать запрос к кнопке, если каждые N-секунд, то к таймеру и т.д.